# Is Function Filters supported for Azure functions using python?

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-webjobssdk

I want to run pre/post processing logic when a azure function is invoked. Currently I have 4-5 azure functions which should run with same pre/post processing logic(only parameters will change).

This article explains a way of doing it in C#: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/do-you-know-azure-function-have-function-filters/

[Comparison says no support for python language](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-compare-logic-apps-ms-flow-webjobs#compare-functions-and-webjobs)

How should I implement this in python function?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no such Filter concept (asp.net MVC like) in python. Even for C#, filter in Function is in preview (which is likely to change).

Alternatively, you can use wsgi app which is now supported in Python Function App. You can override main entrypoint of the function with a wsgi app.

```py
import logging

import azure.functions as func
from ..FlaskApp.wsgi import application # your flask app

main = func.WsgiMiddleware(application).main
```

Or, by more explicitly maintaining the Function entrypoint.

```py
import logging

import azure.functions as func
from ..FlaskApp.wsgi import application # your flask app

def main(req: func.HttpRequest, context: func.Context) -> func.HttpResponse:
    return func.WsgiMiddleware(application).handle(req, context)
```

For some more details on this, refer [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-library/pull/45).

Once you wire up the wsgi integration, you can use a wrapper app (like Flask) for your common pre/post processing logic in middleware (filter like). Refer [Hooking in WSGI Middleware](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#hooking-in-wsgi-middleware).

Comment: My pre/post scripts are not FlaskApp. Will this still work? Also, I did some reading on **AZ Durable functions**. Chaining functions like: **pre script --> ServerlessFunction1 --> post script** satisfies my usecase, but I have to write orchestrators for all Serverless functions. And, it will be invoked by DurableTrigger function. As done in this [example](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-python/tree/dev/samples/function_chaining)

Comment: Yes, durable function would be a good alternative to your need.